# Excel VBA on Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

Im quite new in Excel VBA programming so please bear with me :)

I have this script where it does a VLookup on two sheets as long as Column A is not null

```
Dim i As Single

i = 2

Do While Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value <> " "
    Result = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("H" & i), Sheet2.Range("$A$1:$B$30"), 2, False)
    Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value = Result
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

but I don't understand why the loop still continues to put value on column B when column A is already null.

Am I missing the code to stop the loop?

Comment: `A is already null` mean those cells in A that have never been assigned a value? So yes, I would try `""` aka the empty string checking. -Kf

Comment: Try `Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value <> 0 And IsNumeric(Sheet1.Range("A" & i))` . That tends to work better for me when I'm thinking about my life.

Comment: Or you could try the good old ISEMPTY....  `Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A" & i))`. 

Answer (score 0):

Delcare the sheet you are targeting using it's name (to ensure that you are targeting correct sheet in your look). Something like this:

```
Dim i As Single
Dim TargetSheet as worksheet

Set TargetSheet = Thisworkbook.Sheet("Your sheet name") 'place your sheet name between ""
i = 2

Do While TargetSheet.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" 'make sure the string is empty
    Result = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("H" & i), Sheet2.Range("$A$1:$B$30"), 2, False)
    Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value = Result
    i = i + 1
Loop
```